# Copy row contents to another sheet and clear data except formulas

Tags: google-apps-script

I am needing to copy all data in a row (including formulas and formatting) to another tab (when a checkbox is ticked), and then I want to clear the contents of that row on the source sheet, but keep all formulas in place. I'm working on Google Sheets App Script.

I have been playing around with using range.getFormulas() and range.setFormulas() but I haven't been able to make it work.

This is the current script I have which clears all the content. So I'm wanting to build on this one, hopefully.

And here's an editable link to a copy of the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vUjLrkwuhat28lInKDvCwJgY5BH6U85JDl_U61eeC2A/edit?usp=sharing

```
function onEdit(event) {
// assumes source data in sheet named Day to Day
// target sheet of move to named Total TO/YO
// getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to colu 36 or AJ
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

if(s.getName() == "Day to Day" && r.getColumn() == 36 && r.getValue() == true) {
var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Total TO/YO");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).clearContent();
}
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help sent my way!

Comment: one other solution could be to use arrayformula both in the original tab and the copied tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### This cannot be run without event object provided by trigger

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('Entry')
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Day to Day" && e.range.columnStart == 36 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    var numColumns = sh.getLastColumn();
    var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Total TO/YO");
    var trg = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(trg);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, numColumns).getFormulas().flat().forEach((f, i) => {
      if (!f) {
        sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, i + 1).setValue('')
      }
    })
  }
}
```

If you get error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined` it's probably because you ran it from the script editor without supplying the event object.

Comment: Hey Cooper, this script works to keep the formulas thank you! There is one small issue - it looks to copy the row to the target sheet twice - once with the data in there before it clears, and looks to copy a blank row again once the data has been cleared. Any ideas on this one?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see a second copyTo

Comment: Ahh, it was my bad - I had a trigger set up that was unnecessary. Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it!